# Save dynamic checkbox values to database

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

I am using jquery and codeigniter to save dynamic checkbox values to database. After click on save button the checkbox values can be displayed properly in the jquery function. My problem is my failure in inserting those values to database. Please show me where I'am wrong with my codes.

Thanks in advance.

1-The view

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>List</th><th >Check</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach($val1 as $row){
?>
<tr>
<td>
<?=$row->description;?>
</td>
<td>
<input type='checkbox'  name="cie10"  value="<?=$row->idd?>"  />
</td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

 <button id="save">save</button>
```

2- JQUERY

```
$('#save').on('click', function(event) {
var cie10 = [];
$.each($("input[name='cie10']:checked"), function(){            
cie10.push($(this).val());
;
});
alert(cie10);
var id_pat=100;
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'<?=base_url('admin/savePatientCied')?>',
data: {cie10:cie10,id_pat:id_pat},
success:function(data) {

}});

})
```

3- controller

```
public function savePatientCied()
{
$id_pat = $this->input->post('id_pat');
$cied10 = $this->input->post('cied10');

$id_con=1;

foreach ($cied10 as $key=>$id_ced) {
$save= array(
'diagno_def' => $id_ced,
'con_id_link' => $id_con,
'p_id' =>$id_pat
);
$this->model_admin->SaveConDef($save);
}
}
```

MODEL

```
public function SaveConDef($save) {
$this->db->insert('tablename', $save);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code that's in the SaveConDef() function in model_admin?

Comment: I just edited by adding the SaveConDef()  function.

Comment: You're submitting a value with the name `cie10` with ajax, yet are retrieving `cied10` (with an extra d) in codeigniter. I think you need to change `$cied10 = $this->input->post('cied10');` to `$cied10 = $this->input->post('cie10');`

Comment: hooo la la. You are right man. I couldn't believe this simple error of mine ! Thank you so much man.

Comment: You're welcome :)